# Get Taxonomy term url from sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

So I was wondering if there is a way to get a term url from the sharepoint rest api by selecting the right property...

I have this right now but I have now idea what to select :
`_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/{groupId}/sets/{setId}/terms/{termId}?$select=*,{URL?}`

What should I replace URL with ?

Comment: Today I came across the same problem. Not only I want to get the associated link with the term but I also would like to set the link for a given term. I spent all day looking for a solution. Have you managed to find the solution?

Mark

Comment: I don't remember which property it is but you can reverse api to find it :)